# Issue with string variable: "No operator << matches these operands"

Tags: c++, string

I'm having an issue with a string variable.

I'm using it to output some debug information for some customer objects.

I want to return their name and the yearofbirth in the form of a string, mostly to check things are where they're supposed to be and information is correct.

```
std::string ToString()
    {
        std::string output;
        output = getName() << " " << std::to_string(getYear());
        return output;
    }
```

I have no idea why this won't compile. Any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: if `getName()` returns a `std::string` then all of those `<<`s need to be `+`s

Comment: Thank-you. That seemed to fix it.

Comment: OK.  I am voting to close as a typo then.

Comment: Or you declare `output` a stringstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that `getName()` returns a string:

```
std::string output;
output = getName() + " " + std::to_string(getYear());
return output;
```

Or

```
std::stringstream message;
message << getName() << " " << getYear();
return message.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
output = getName() + " " + std::to_string(getYear());
```

provided that function `getName` returns an object of type `std::string`